# .NET transaction management without TransactionScope

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, transactions, transactionscope

I was actively using TransactionScope in my application and was happy. But now I came to the situation where TransactionScope is not enough flexible: first of all, because I can't change IsolationLevel dynamically.

What is the easiest way to replace TransactionScope by database transaction which can be managed manually? One of the features I want to keep is the support of cross-connections transactions.

Comment: When you say "dynamically" - do you mean once it has started? No, you can't - but you can of course specify the transaction level at the *start*. What would it even *mean* to change isolation level part way through a distributed transaction?

Comment: I described the problem in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996524/transactionscope-nuances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the conculsion is that you cannot do this: Have both a distributed transaction and change the isolation level.

You cannot change the isolation level of a transaction after it has started.

To use cross connection transactons you need to use transaction scope, or a COM+ transaction via enterprise services. In both cases you cannot change the isolation level after the transaction is created.

It is possible to to change the isolation level of a SQL connection using the "set transaction isolation level " SQL statement.

Comment: Are you sure about sub-scopes with different isolation levels?

Comment: @Idsa, there is an example of that in the link I gave, one use of it is if you have logging, and you do not want the logging to be rolled back when the rest is rolled back.

Comment: There is just an example of using out-of-transaction blocks (TransactionScopeOption.Suppress). But I would like to keep all my code inside a transaction.

Comment: @Shiraz Bhaiji: All transactionscopes in the example you have provied use the same (default, which is Serializable) IsolationLevel

Comment: @Shiraz Bhaiji: It will fail at runtime. The quote from the link you have provided above: "
When using nested TransactionScope objects, all nested scopes must be configured to use exactly the same isolation level if they want to join the ambient transaction. If a nested TransactionScope object tries to join the ambient transaction yet it specifies a different isolation level, an ArgumentException is thrown."